# "host1$ ssh host2 cmd1 | cmd2" on which host will cmd2 run?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

```
host1$ ssh host2 cmd1 | cmd2
```

Will cmd2 run on host1 or host2?

e.g.:

```
host1$ ssh host2 ls -1 / | wc -l
```

In this example, will `wc -l` run on host1 or host2, why?

Comment: this is pretty easy to find out for yourself: `ssh host2 echo | hostname`

Comment: @Eevee, actually, I know the answer, what I want to know is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run on the local host, because shell will recognize '|' as pipe before invoking ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'echo $HOSTNAME' as cmd2, and it will clearly give you the correct answer

Answer (score -1):

It will run on host2 because the pipe ends the first command.  To get cmd2 running on host1, escape the pipe:

host1$ ssh host2 cmd1 \| cmd2